# DB2 Full Text Search IQQD0040E Error

Tags: full-text-search, db2

I have a production database running DB2 at 10.1.2 workgroup (OpenSuse 12.2) and I have Full Text Search running pretty well there. Now I'm trying to build a test enviroment, but when I turn over de production backup into test machine with 10.1.2 express-c the FTS is presenting this error:

```
    <message>IQQD0040E The client specified the wrong authentication token.
    com.ibm.es.nuvo.inyo.common.InyoFactoryWrapper.authenticate(InyoFactoryWrapper.java:203)
    com.ibm.es.nuvo.inyo.common.InyoFactoryWrapper.getHandler(InyoFactoryWrapper.java:85)
    com.ibm.es.nuvo.inyo.common.InyoServer$InyoListener.run(InyoServer.java:425)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1121)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:614)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:769)</message>
```

The redbook says to me that this error cause is: "Usually this error occurs when there are 2 or more text search instances configured with the same port number and one instance is already running".

I've already searched other instances but I've only found one. So "usually" does not apply to my situation.

Anyone know what else I can do to fix that?

Best regards,
jacker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out a solution. When the backup is transported to a new instance of DB2, de FTS application engage it communication with a token. After restored, we just need to go to the bin directory of FTS, commonly at /home/db2inst1/db2tss/bin and run this command:

```
   configTool generateToken -seed <username> -configPath ~/sqllib/db2tss/config
```

Hope this help anyone who's passing by this trouble.

Regards.